# Force subscribe to channel to use the bot [aiogram]

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I have a simple chat-bot writed with aiogram for receiving messages from users and answering to them. I want to make sure that user is subscribed to a particular channel before he can use my bot. How can I implement that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) method and then check `status` field of the [ChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember)

Comment: thanks, I did like that: 
`check_member = await bot.get_chat_member(-1214166516038, message.from_user.id)` 
`if check_member.status not in ["member", "creator"]:` 
`return await message.reply("<b>some text</b>", reply_markup=builderz.as_markup())`